# EACCES error in VSCode if it's started from the command line of Far Manager

Tags: visual-studio-code, far

I love to use FarManager as a file explorer in Windows. But I face the same problem each time I try to run the Visual Studio Code from the FarManager's command line:

```
Error from the extension host: spawn C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe EACCES
```

The VS Code is started using the following command in the FarManager's command line:

```
code .
```

Comment: I don't have any issues in starting VS Code from Far Manager. I would try to see which files are read/loaded/executed or **not found** with the help of [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). VS Code may fail to start another application, so I would also try to disable the VS Code extensions to try to find the culprit. Can you start code from a normal `cmd` instance? The issue may have nothing to do with Far Manager.

Comment: Hi. VS Code works if it's started from cmd.exe and it doesn't work if it's started from Far. I see no difference in PE.